# How to keep radio selected states when hitting browser back button?

Tags: php

I am handling a survey multistep form with many radio sets.

They have some default states

User operates over them to select his preferences.

Now the client wants when hitting either browser back button or the side navigator links (a set of links pointing to previous stages of the survey) to have the radio states the user previously chose.

Here is how the navigator looks like:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php?site=form1">Step1</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?site=form2">Step2</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?site=form3">Step3</a></li>
</ul>
```

There is only one $_SESSION that collects data throughout the survey.

I know I can load information directly from $_SESSION but I need to replace the default states when the request comes from the navigator links/ back button.

Comment: Do you mean if they go to any of the pages their choice should be remembered? Server side or user side?

Comment: `localStorage` is probably your best bet.

Comment: @Pez Cuckow: I meant user side. To Madara Uchiha: nice idea, but not sure how easy is to check the user support of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main approaches to this, basically you are saying that the chosen state of the radio's need to be saved between different pages of your form.

So when you return to a page you were on previously but without submitting, the choices should still be the same.

There are two key approaches, server side with PHP or client side with Javascript

**PHP**

You can set any link on the website to submit the form and you could save the radio selections, then when you create the form you can check the previously selected value

This information could be saved in `$_SESSION` but they'd need to submit the form each time they changed the page (you could change the links to do this)

**Javascript**

You could write some javascript that remembered the content of the selections and stored them in the users browser as a cookie, this could update everytime they clicked a button. When the page loads the javascript would check for cookies (or local storage) and would load the previous options.

When they finish and submit the form you'd clear the javascript

Basic example

```
$('form input[type=radio]:checked')
```

Once I have more information I'll flesh out this answer further

Comment: There are already default states on radio buttons. 1. How to replace them with the information from $_SESSION? 2. How to detect the request came from later states of the survey?

Answer (score 0):

After posting form, you can save values in the session. When accessing previous page again (or even first load it), read session's values and check specified radios. If you access page first time, there will be no data in the session, so no one will be checked.

You can also store selected values lively with JavaScript and cookies.

Comment: I would like to use your idea. Can you suggest me how to alter the checked="checked" state using the information from $_SESSION?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" <?php if($_SESSION['checkbox1'] == "Checked"){ echo "checked"}?> value="" id="" name="" />

Answer (score 0):

A very simplified possible solution:

```
<?php
   session_start(); // this needs to be at the top of all pages using $_SESSION (before anything else) else $_SESSION will always be empty
   if($_POST['vehicle']){
      $_SESSION['checkbox1'] = $_POST['vehicle'];
   }
print_r($_SESSION); // remove this line after testing. It will show you the contents of the $_SESSION, which is handy for seeing when variables are set within it
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"<?php if($_SESSION['checkbox1'] == "Bike"){ echo " checked"}?>>I have a bike<br />
   <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"<?php if($_SESSION['checkbox1'] == "Car"){ echo " checked"}?>>I have a car <br />#
   <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You could add a unique id generated at the first page in a hidden input area that when posted could form part of the session variable name. From there the information would be indexed in the $_SESSION under that variable name making it easier to pull the data back out or to create a new form session as it were.

Hope I haven't lost you.

Comment: I tried your solution. The problem is that in my multistep, `$_POST['vehicle']` is always emtpy on form1 (first step). I can only display it on the next page and then when I revert back is empty again. I must admit I don't understand why this variable resets when go back.

Comment: Balls. I forgot to put session_start(); in the top of the PHP code before anything else. Please see the edited code. :S Rookie mistake haha

Comment: No no, I already did that. the session work fine. Only that being a multiform I use action="<?php print $config['baseurl']; ?>/index.php?site=form2" so there is no session sets on the form1